# PHP won't echo out the $_POST 

Tags: php

got a small problem, this code

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<?php
...
echo '<input name="textfield" type="text" id="textfield" value="Roger" />';
echo 'Hello, '.$_POST['textfield'].'<br>';
...
?></p>
</form>
```

should echo out "Hello, Roger", as roger is the default value, yet it gives out only "Hello, " and nothing else. Any suggestions?

edit: yes, there's a form.

Thanks!

Comment: I supose there are a form, isn't it?

Comment: We need to see more code. Examine the page in Firebug to ensure that the POST data is actually getting sent.

Comment: Can we safely assume that the second echo statement is being executed on a post of a page containing the first?

Comment: Just a note: I see a close `</p>` in the example but no open `<p>`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are echoing the text box and at the same time hoping to gets its value, which is not possible.

```
echo '<input name="textfield" type="text" id="textfield" value="Roger" />';
echo 'Hello, '.$_POST['textfield'].'<br>';
```

You need to first submit the form with method set to `post` and only then you can get its value.

**Example:**

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
...
<input name="textfield" type="text" id="textfield" value="Roger" />
...
<input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    echo 'Hello, '.$_POST['textfield'].'<br>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! Now it works. yet is there a way for php to echo out the default value ( or a new value once it is typed in ) without having to press the 'submit' button?

Comment: @user296516: You can get value only when form is submitted. If you meant without submitting form, then you can use the javascript for that, but it won't be avaliable to PHP.

Comment: Yes, say `if(!isset($_POST['submit'])) { echo 'Hello, Roger.'; }`

Answer (score 3):

Try `print_r($_POST)` or `var_dump($_POST)` to see if any POST data gets submitted.

Edit: Did you specify POST as the submit method in your form tag? Do you submit the form? Please show the entire `<form>`-Tag.

Answer (score 2):

If this is, exactly, your code then the problem is that the $_POST is not set yet since no form is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

- check the css (is it hidden..?=
- check the source for the page (does the input field appear?)
- don't forget to wrap the input in a form if you want to submit it back to the same page.

Answer (score 0):

My guess it, that the server doesn't allocate `$_GET` and/or `$_POST`. You could check that in the php configuration.

Have a look if you can access the data via `$_REQUEST`, which should unify get and post data.

Comment: But don't use `$_REQUEST` in production, only for debugging. It's bad practice to use it in live systems.